# Use JSON database with Node & React

Tags: json, node.js, database, reactjs, store

I'm developing a web app with Node.js and React.

A JSON file is used to store the text data and a repository for pictures I use. It is modified by Node.js and the data is rendered by React.

I would like to know the good pratice to work with a JSON database.
Can I store the JSON file in local and render it with React outside the src folder or should I store the JSON file on the server (Node.js) and parse it on React via requests ? And how?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From Node v8.9.1 onwards, you can access JSON file with a simple require.

```
var json = require('/location/of/file/file.json');
```

In terms of location stick it outside the `src` because it is not getting complied. I tend to put it in the root folder called `config`.

The file should be stored on the server, as your using node to get the data from it and there may be sensitive data in there.

Then again it all depends on your situation, if your web app needs a backend for it to work and it is not just a static web app use node as above, if it is just static content just put the config in the UI (as long as it does not contain any sensitive data in it).

Comment: Yes I tried this solution but I used create-react-app and it prohibits imports from outside the src folder...

Answer (score 0):

I seems like that you're making an static app ( such as a blog ). If you're doing server-sider rendering, you can just require your JSON db and then hydrate your DOM. Otherwise you can expose an API endpoint and ask for the JSON and let the client-side React handle it. Hope this helps!

Comment: No I'm doing a dynamic app. The client is able to modify the data and the data is rendered according to.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a JSON file directly to store information.

Try using some NoSql DB technology designed to do that, like MongoDB. You can use it as a service for free from mlab.com for up to 500MB of data.

There are many other providers out there, like mongodb.com/cloud/atlas, from the creators of MongoDB.

Comment: Yes I understand but I need to finish my project really quick. Do you have a solution using a JSON file?

Comment: Getting started with mongodb is really fast. If you use a json file instead, you will have to build all your reading and writing logics, wich will take a lot of time. MongoDB comes with all this in it's core engine, and the commands you have to write are quite simple. Search for something like "getting started with mongodb node" and you find some direct to the point tutorials. In less than one day you can do what you want, I'm pretty sure of it.

Comment: In here you can find a really simple tutorial showing how to implement MongoDB in node using Mongoose, a module for node that manipulates to original MongoDB module for node that ease things up: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-mongoose-for-mongodb-and-nodejs--cms-29527

Comment: Okey I will try to use Mongo for the JSON database. For the pictures I need to store I guess I can store them directly on my server and send to my client thaks to http requests? Thank you

Comment: Yes, you could store it in your server, but you should store it in a CDN like Amazon S3 using the aws-sdk node module. By doing this you delegate the images requests and data transfers to a third-part server (from Amazon) and keep your node server free of RAM/CPU usage to focus on your core services. Also, node runs in a single-threaded environment, and all other incoming requests won't be triggered until all ongoing requests are finished, including image transfers.